# mongrel_rails - programatically report which port it's running on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

On my local machine, i run rails with mongrel.  I have some stuff which runs when it starts, via a file in config/initializers, which uses `puts` to tell me which database it's using, what is being used to send emails, and a few other bits of info.

When I run a cluster of mongrels, on ports 3000, 3001 and 3002, I only want to do this reporting stuff for the mongrel on port 3000.  So, I need to wrap it in an `if` block which tests which port the currently running mongrel is using.  Can anyone tell me how I can get this in my code?

Answer (score 2):

in an initializer,

```
puts Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]
```

can report your port.

Comment: Thanks @Alper - sorry, i should have said that the app in question is running **Rails 2.2.2**.  Your code is erroring for me with `uninitialized constant Rails::Server` - i don't suppose you know the Rails 2 equivalent?

Comment: that's just the mode, eg "development"

Comment: "3000" doesn't appear anywhere in `ENV.inspect` either.

Comment: Max, can you check if this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.2.1/Rails/MongrelServer/Start/run) can help? that `defaults` object, or `RailsConfigurator` class? I m just failing setting rails env. Which ruby version are you on?

Comment: Ruby 1.8.6  (i know, i know!  We're trying to upgrade but it's tough)

Comment: I can access `Mongrel::Rails::RailsConfigurator` in my script.  I can't figure out how to get at the config or port number though.

Comment: Ok i finally got the environment. I know this won't be the best way, but, maybe you can just try using ARGV[] array?

Comment: I'm just getting an empty array for ARGV, when i do `puts ARGV.inspect` in my script.

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, but i can just stick with the solution in my answer if this is turning into a timesink :)

Comment: np :) yesterday i was happy feeling like returned back to good old days, but now looking again at the rails 2 code.. this is just something totally different then what we are using now.. :) good luck on your upgrade process :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm answering my own question as i just figured it out after setting a bounty!

I can get the **pid** of the currently running process with `Process.pid`.   Then i can do `ps afx | grep mongrel` which gives me a result like this

```
 pid                                                                                 port
  |                                                                                    |
  V                                                                                    V
10761 pts/1    S      0:20  |   \_/usr/local/bin/ruby /path/to/mongrel_rails start -p 3000
10762 pts/1    S      0:18  |   \_/usr/local/bin/ruby /path/to/mongrel_rails start -p 3001
10763 pts/1    S+     0:23  |   \_/usr/local/bin/ruby /path/to/mongrel_rails start -p 3002
```

which i can then grep for the pid, and read the port number out of the matching line, and see if it's 3000.

So, my code is

```
if `ps afx | grep mongrel_rails`.split("\n").detect{|line| line =~ /^#{Process.pid}.+\-p\s3000/}
  #this is a mongrel running on port 3000 - do the extra stuff
  ....
end
```

BTW, if someone can tell me how to directly get the port of the running mongrel, without going via `ps afx` and `Process.pid` i'll still give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work in 2.2.2?

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
        @port = request.port
  end
end
```

Comment: He is trying to get it inside an initializer. So this wont work.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I missed that. I'm new to rails and glossed over it.